# jquery tokeninput read items from database

Tags: php, ajax, json, joomla, jquery-tokeninput

how can read items of jquery from database with php and ajax?
I use this plugin : http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput
this is my jquery code :

```
$("#demo-input-local").tokenInput(
'http://exapmle.com/index.php/mantaghe', { 
theme: "facebook",
hintText: "Know of any cool games?",
noResultsText: "Nothin' found.",
searchingText: "Gaming...",
preventDuplicates: true
}   
);
```

This is my php code in this url http://exapmle.com/index.php/mantaghe :

```
$db = JFactory :: getdbo();
$sql1 = "select * from sb5qt_djcf_regions where parent_id='0'";
$db ->setquery($sql1);
$result = $db -> loadAssocList();
$str = array( "id" => "value",
"name" => "value",
"mantaghe" => "value");
foreach($result as $res)
{
$str['mantaghe'] = $res['mantaghe'];
$str['id'] = $res['id'];
$str['name']= $res['name']; 
}
echo json_encode($str);
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Can you add the JSON string that is returned from the server.

Comment: it can not find any words.I don't know where can I alert JSON string that is returned from the server in my jquery code.

Comment: going to the web address should do it.

Comment: it returned: {"id":"504","name":"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u06cc","mantaghe":"0"}  name is not true. when i search \u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u06cc also it can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments your service returned:

```
{"id":"504","name":"\u0645\u0631\u06a9\u0632\u06cc","mantaghe":"0"}
```

The service must return a JSON *array*, rather than a single object. Although looking at your PHP, it looks like you may have got a bit mixed up writing it - you're current code is constantly overwriting the properties of one single object, rather than creating an array of objects.

I haven't written any PHP in years, so the syntax is probably wrong, but you want something more like this.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($result as $res)
{
$token['mantaghe'] = $res['mantaghe'];
$token['id'] = $res['id'];
$token['name']= $res['name'];
$arr[] = $token;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thanks.you're right...I change it to return array but it doesn't work again.it stay at Gaming... even not write Nothin' found.

Comment: @viol What does the JSON look like now?

Comment: that is look like this : [{"id":"12","name":"\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646 ","mantaghe":"0"},{"id":"177","name":"\u0628\u0648\u0634\u0647\u0631","mantaghe":"0"}]

Comment: @viol - have you tried it returning standard ascii strings instead?